# Can I paint my floor in two stages with epoxy?

Tags: concrete, basement, epoxy

We just redid our basement floor and I am considering epoxy paint (with texture flakes) for the floor.  I prefer not to move everything out again for this process, so I'm considering moving everything left, paint, then everything right and finishing.  Of course, I will wait for it to cure.

Question is, can I do half the floor and come back after curing and to the rest without making a big mess of the transition line?  Will there be any adhesion issue at the line? And as a bonus - how best to do the transition line?

Comment: "You do the hokey pokey
And you turn yourself around,
That's what it's all about"

Comment: The transition line is the key here.  Might be hard to totally hide it.  What finish are you looking at?  The thickness of the material will matter.

Comment: I'm not too concerned about cosmetics. It is a basement.  I also plan to use texture flakes.  I assume this will help hide the line.

Comment: Oh, if you're using flakes then what is the real concern?  I think that will hide any transition almost completely.  I was thinking about a clear or solid color smooth floor when talking about the transition.

Comment: I'm most concerned about adhesion at the transition. Question modified

Comment: epoxy sticks well to dried epoxy.

Answer (score 3):

1. Do an experiment on a slab of anything of similar roughness -- a chunk of garage floor would do.
2. Make a virtue out of a necessity:

   - Make the edge at a logical division of the space, and change colours of paint, or change colours of glitter at the transition. If you want to be fancy, make it a zig-zag or Peano curve
   - Mask shapes onto the floor.  Stack the stuff on the shapes.  Move stuff back, Do rest of floor.
   - Apply the glitter as a secondary cover mixed with a clear coat.  Apply it with a stencil in blocks. The pattern of glitter distracts from the seam.
   - Instead of left/right, move everything to the edge, measure the maximum distance from the edge of the room.  Mark a rectangle with that distance from all the walls.  Do the centre.  Now move everything into the centre and do the edge.  Can be really cool if you change colours of paint.  (Buy one additional colour, and mix it into all the remaining paint.  So if you did the center in light green, buying a can of dark blue would make the remaining paint dark green-blue.  Yellow + blue grey = brown.

If you want to have more fun, use a stencil, and lay down patterns of the edge colour as a second coat on the centre area.

Comment: Thanks for challenging me to think creatively.  Not a strength

Answer (score 2):

I would consider making the smallest pile of everything and putting the transition where it will be least noticed - if that is a quarter section then fine.

But have the transition hidden as much as possible or obscured - sofa or table etc etc

Comment: Good ideas and thanks.  This side of the basement is my brewhouse and workshop. Hadn't considered a sofa...

Comment: Useful after testing the brew?... :)